# What does the "Reset publish profile" button do on Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

On Azure Portal, there is a button to reset publish profile for Azure Functions. What does it exactly do? Would the running app throw 503 errors while the profile is being reset?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Resets all of the passwords generated for this resource, for the credentials stored in the "Publish Profile". E.g. FTP Password.

Answer (score 1):

As part of **Get publish profile** from Azure portal, you would have downloaded a setting file which comprises of UserName and password which will give access to things like publish code from Visual studio, FTP etc. You might have shared profile setting file with your colleague or team members, now if you want to ensure the profile setting file to void then clicking **Reset publish profile** will ensure, with old settings people wont be authorized to publish the code.